# MS SQL Server: Best Practice to run the same code on multiple tables with identical structure

Tags: sql-server

I have two different tables which are identical in structure. I have to run the same code on both of them, but at different times and the results have to be saved in seperate destinations. Currently this works by having two separate stored procedures which contain the same code, apart from the source table in the FROM-statement.

This doesn't strike me as very elegant, and changes to the processing have to be done in both stored procedures. How do I combine them in a way that they can still be called separely? Naively I thought I could use a function and give the target and source table as a variable. But my research in table functions revealed that you have to "fill" the table variable with the whole content of the source table first, and I would guess that this decreases performance quite a bit, compared to calling the table directly in a procedure with the FROM statement?

What does SQL Server offer to solve this in a more elegant way?

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Why not define the source table as a parameter of your SP? You could also add the output location as a second parameter.

Comment: ok thanks, I will look up the use of parameters. Still a beginner.

Comment: What do you mean with "saved in seperate destinations"? CSV? Temp Table?

Comment: The results are saved in other tables. I am currently looking up ways to declare tables as parameters - if I succeed, I will close the topic. Any further tips are appreciated though, thank you

Comment: tablenames are just strings so this should n't be too much of an hassle...

Comment: Do I have to make a concatenated string out of the whole query/code and execute this string? Or can the table name be interpreted within a regular query?

Comment: Ask yourself why you have two tables with the same structure. Should they, in fact, be a *single* table with (part of) the separate table names actually modelled as column *values*? I.e., I'd hope you'd see it as almost certainly wrong to have `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables?

Comment: One is larger and processed monthly, one is small and processed daily. Currently they are merged AFTER processing. I guess I could try to find a way to merge them first, but process only the newly merged part again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two different tables which are identical in structure.  I have to run the same code on both of them
>   . . .
>   What does SQL Server offer to solve this in a more elegant way?

Your choices are to keep them separate, or use dynamic SQL.  Inelegant schemas require inelegant code.

To help with the maintenance of the two procedures, you could use a script to generate both the stored procedures, so you have a single place to make changes.

Comment: "Inelegant schemas require inelegant code." - this is brilliant sir!!!